# Replace create_function with empty $args for PHP 8

Tags: php, function, deprecated, create-function

I'm having trouble rewriting this line of code that contains create_function() in preparation for updating to PHP 8+.

The line of code to replace is:

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("Ctxt_Menu_Widget");'));
```

I am trying to replace it with:

```
$callback = function(){
    ('', 'return register_widget("Ctxt_Menu_Widget");');
}
add_action('widgets_init', $callback);
```

But obviously, this isn't right, the replacement code won't allow the array withing that function.

Can someone help me rewrite this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The function should be a real (anonimous) function, sintactically valid in php, so it should be something like that

```
$callback = function(){
    return register_widget("Ctxt_Menu_Widget");
}
```

Then you can call this function

```
add_action('widgets_init', $callback);
```

Now wehn called, it is executed as a normal php functions

Comment: Thanks @Daniele, but what did work for me was as follows:

`add_action ( 'widgets_init', 'Ctxt_init_Menu_Widget' );
 function Ctxt_init_Menu_Widget() {
 return register_widget('Ctxt_Menu_Widget');
}`

Comment: It is exactly the same. You declare a function named Ctxt_init_Menu_Widget and call inside add_action.
  If you "put" the function inside a variable and use that variable, you should get the same results as per your solution. But, if you solved in that way, nopro, maybe this is a framework I don't know and this kind of solution doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

What turns out to be a good solution was:

```
add_action ( 'widgets_init', 'Ctxt_init_Menu_Widget' );
    function Ctxt_init_Menu_Widget() {
    return register_widget('Ctxt_Menu_Widget');
}
```

to replace:

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("Ctxt_init_Menu_Widget");'));
```

Source: https://sarah-moyer.com/fix-create_function-deprecated-in-wordpress/

Comment: `create_function()` would return an anonymous function that's only ever used by reference. This code creates a new _named_ function and this code will behave oddly in anything other than the global scope.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).